# Hosting with AWS amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am planning to build a real state website and I will be hosting it with AWS amplify, my audience are in Saudi Arabia, will there be any restrictions related to their policies when they access the website? will they be able to access it?

Comment: Are you asking this from a technical perspective, or from a political / legal perspective?

Comment: Any perspective, I'd like to know any possible issues that will occur.